# Objective-C, correctly separate columns in CSV by comma

Tags: objective-c, csv

I have an Excel file that I exported as a CSV file.

Some of the data in the columns also have commas. CSV escapes these by putting the string in the column in quotes (""). However, when I try to parse it in Objective-C, the comma inside the string seperates the data, as if it were a new column.

Here's what I have:

```
self.csvData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:file encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

//This is what the data looks like:
//"123 Testing (Sesame Street, Testing)",Hello World,Foo,Bar

//Get rows
NSArray *lines = [self.csvData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

//Get columns
NSArray *columns = [[lines objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

//Show columns
for (NSString *column in columns) {
    NSLog(@"%@", column);
}

//Console shows this:
"123 Testing (Sesame Street
Testing)"
Hello World
Foo
Bar
```

Notice how `"123 Testing (Sesame Street` and `Testing)"` are output as separate columns. I need these to be one. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use regular expression in iPhone app to separate string by , (comma)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083616/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-iphone-app-to-separate-string-by-comma)

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Design an algorithm.

At the start of the input you have one of three possibilities:

1. You have a `"` - parse a quoted field
2. You have a `,` - handle an empty field
3. Otherwise - parse a non-quoted field

After parsing if there is any more input left then iterate (loop).

You might start with some variables:

```
NSUInteger position = 0;                // current position
NSUInteger remaining = csvData.length;  // left to parse
```

then enter your loop:

```
while(remaining > 0)
{
```

get the next character:

```
   unichar nextChar = [csvData characterAtIndex:position];
```

Now check if that character is a `"`, `,` or something else. You can use an `if` or a `switch`.

Let's say it's a comma, then you want to find the position of the next comma. The `NSString` method `rangeOfString:options:range` will give you that. The last argument to this method is a range specifying in which part of the string to search for the comma. You can construct that range using `NSMakeRange` and values derived from `position` and `remaining`.

Once you have the next comma you need to extract the field, the `substringWithRange:` method can get you that.

Finally update `position` and `remaining` as required and you are ready for the next iteration.

You'll have to handle a few error cases - e.g. opening quote with no closing quote. Overall it is straight forward.

If you start down this path and it doesn't work ask a new question, showing your code and explaining where you got stuck.

HTH